# empirical estimation of Bernoulli distribution (lower bound)

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_i$ be an i.i.d. Bernoulli distributed sequence, with probability $p$ being 1. Now consider an empirical estimation of $p$ with $l$ samples and I am looking for a lower bound for following probability with assumption of $lp>1$

$$
\mathbb{P}\left\{ \frac{1}{l} \sum_{i=1}^l X_i \geq p \right\}
$$

The desired lower bound should be independent of $l$ and $p$. My guess is $1/4$.

**Note**: It's $\geq$, not $>$.

**Some background**: I am reading Vapnik's "Statistical Learning Theory". Proof of the lemma 4.1 claims that for $lp > 1$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left\{ \frac{1}{l} \sum_{i=1}^l X_i > p \right\} \leq 1/4
$$
However, note that here it is an upper bound and it breaks the proof. I think we should seek for a lower bound the bias probability instead.

Thanks

Comment: I also ran into this and came across this proof: https://cs.nyu.edu/media/publications/binomial.pdf

Comment: Also I believe that is a typo in Vapnik's proof. The next step following the claim noted above is actually applying the opposite relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe MONODA43's comment answer my question.

1. it is typo 2) the lower bound proof can be found in cs.nyu.edu/media/publications/binomial.pdf